# Discord.Net Server requested a reconnect causing music player problems

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am running into an issue where my bot is being required to reconnect, making it leave any calls it was in. I am using Lavalink to serve the music and it is very problematic when the bot restarts itself, having to make it rejoin calls and attempt to continue playing. Additionally, I will sometimes get "A disconnected handler is blocking the gateway task, therefore, the bot never fully restarts.

I don't know what to tell my users as I can't stop the reconnects, are there any ways I can at least make the bot continue playing or something along those lines when it reconnects?

The console log of a reconnect:

```
system.exception: server requested a reconnect at system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.throwfornonsuccess(task task)
```

Comment: Use the [nightly](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/nightlies.html#installing-with-myget-recommended) build which should resume the session